# What is the minimal installation possible in order to run a .jar Java file?

Tags: windows-7, java, user-accounts, jdk

I wish to run a small utility ("[Nightly Updater](https://forum.simutrans.com/index.php/topic,17760.msg169452.html#msg169452)", NU) for a game called Simutrans.

NU comes in the form of a .jar file and the only system requirement for NU is Java 9.

I have Java 8 installed in my system (which it seems that I need to keep in order for other, older programs to run).

It seems that Java 9 [is no longer available](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html), but I assume that Java 12 will have backwards compatibility with Java 9 programs.

That Java 12 installation page is telling me to download a "[Development Kit](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk12-downloads-5295953.html)" that uses almost half a gigabyte of disk space, but I don't want an IDE or any other development tools so this seems to be inappropriate. I would like to download just enough to run NU as a user in Windows 7 (preferably in a user, not administrator, account) and no more.

What is the minimal Java installation necessary to run NU? Where do I find it, please?

I am using 64-bit Windows 7.

Comment: Please make sure you're on the right Java download page. Go to Java.com and just follow the instructions to install the latest version of the JRE (Java Runtime Environment).

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion. But Java.com (https://www.java.com/en/download/windows-64bit.jsp) says that I should download Java 8 u211, which I already have. NU requires Java 9.

Comment: @music2myear JRE is no longer available as a separate download with new versions of Java.

Comment: That makes sense. So, Java 8 is the last version with the JRE released independently. Java 9 and later are supposed to only be useful to devs and so are only packaged for devs, as the JDK, and the expectation is the devs will package the necessary java bits in their deployments.

Comment: I have no experience with them, but SAP has a fork of OpenJDK that includes JRE releases of current versions.  https://github.com/SAP/SapMachine/releases

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Traditionally, you would want the Java Runtime Environment (JRE), but this is no longer available separately with current versions of Java.  Why?  Oracle now expects all developers to include a Java runtime with Java-based applications.  If the developer didn't do this, you are now forced to install the JDK.

There's also ways of running a Java applet without any Java installed.  For example, if you download the JDK and extract only `appletviewer.exe` and `jli.dll`, you can use these to run most applets "portably".  This was also discontinued with Java 9.

Comment: Thank you. The Java 12 JDK includes the second file (C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-12.0.1\bin\jli.dll). But I can't find the first file, `appletviewer.exe` (or any Java files named `*view*`).

Comment: The [Java 9 documentation for appletviewer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/tools/appletviewer.htm#JSWOR612) says that "_Although available and supported in JDK 9, the Applet API is marked as deprecated in preparation for removal in a future release._" Does anyone know a way to replicate this functionality in Java 12, please?

Comment: @Matthew You're right, I don't see it in Java 11 either (the current LTS release).  I updated my answer.

Comment: @Matthew - It was removed.  There would be copyright issues if somebody were to include it more than likely.

Comment: @Matthew: Java Applets are officially deprecated since January, 2016. But it was clear as far as back as 2006 that Java Applets should no longer be used. There's nothing you can do other than complain to the authors of Nightly Updater for building upon technologies that should have died 10 years ago.

Comment: @JörgWMittag Thank you for your advice. The issue here is licensing. NU uses the Artistic Licence so that it can be distributed with Simutrans (which is its only use case). The Java licensing rules are rather complicated, but at first glance it appears that the Simutrans project isn't able to distribute Java files itself, so we can't release the NU as a runtime with Simutrans.

Comment: What do you mean by "expects all developers to include a Java runtime with Java-based applications? Does it mean developers include JRE inside jar? Would it mean a single jar would be enough to run Java program in that case?

Comment: I'm not a developer, but .jar files are "applets", and these aren't supported anymore.  Only applications created with Java are supported, and they don't have any JRE dependencies.